# How to modify the uptime command on shell?

Tags: shell, openwrt, uptime, ash

When I type in `uptime` in terminal it gives me something like this

```
 16:44:17 up  7:50,  load average: 0.31, 0.47, 0.54
```

I want to make it to be something like this

```
Uptime: 7h 50m
Load average: 0.31, 0.47, 0.54
```

and save it to `uptime.txt`

How can I do that? I'm sorry for the dumb question, I'm still new in this and I've googled before but I find nothing useful.

Comment: You’re probably getting downvotes because you showed us no code of your own. [SO] is not a code writing service, it’s a community of programmers. Even as a beginner, you should be able to show us some code so that we know what you know and can fill in the missing bits. It there are too many of those, this question is too broad and it cannot be answered here; the answers would be extremely long.

Comment: I didn't know that, I registered just yesterday. I'll try to come up with my own codes next time, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ugly command will work:

```
uptime | sed 's#[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]##g' | sed 's#:#h #g' | sed -E 's#, [^,]+users,#m#g' | sed 's/ days,/d/g'|sed 's/  up/Uptime:/g' | sed 's/load averageh/\nLoad average:/g'
```

Comment: it shows 

`Uptime:  8h 42,
Load average:  1.68, 1.65, 1.45`

how to add "m" on `42` ? the minute word isn't showing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` with `uptime`:

```
uptime | awk -F ' up | load average:' '{sub(/,.*$/, "", $2); 
             printf "Uptime: %s\nLoad average: %s\n", $2, $NF}'
Uptime: 23 days 16:14
Load average:  2.19, 1.91, 1.88
```